# copy of an array into a vector not happening as expected

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to copy an array to a vector.

```
int A[1000]; //This array is filled by some function
vector<int> vec;

//some position from which I want to write the contents of the array into vector
int x = some_position;

vec.resize(sizeof(A)+x);
vec.insert(vec.begin()+x, A, A+sizeof(A));
```

The problem is that every fourth element is not copied correctly. The rest of the elements are copied correctly. i.e vec[x+3] != A[x+3]
 for x=0,1,2,3....

Comment: I don't think sizeof(A) returns the array size. Did you check it?

Answer (score 4):

First off, you need to check your understanding of `sizeof`. It returns the number of bytes needed for `A` as a whole, not the number of items in A, for that you would need `sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A)`.

```
int A[1000];
vector<int> vec;

int x = 5;

vec.resize(x + sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A));
vec.insert(vec.begin()+x, A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A));
```

It's also worth noting that 'insert' may not be what you want. If your objective is to treat the vector like an array and overwrite a 1000 element long section of the vector, then you should use std::copy instead. Insert will resize the array even more, so if the resize will make the vector 1005 elements long, and them you start inserting at position 5, then the final vector will be 2005 elements long, with the contents of A going from 5 - 1004.

You could instead replace the `insert` line with this:

```
std::copy(A, A + sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A), vec.begin() + x);
```

This would overwrite the contents of the vector starting at position 5 and leave the vector sized at 1005.

Comment: The `reserve` doesn't really change anything, because pointers are random access iterators, and inserting a range specified by random access iterators is guaranteed to not do more than one reallocation.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong: without a resize, `vec.begin() + 5` is undefined behavior (and will crash with any good library implementation, at least in debug mode).

Comment: It's also worth noting that the OPs code (resize followed by insert) would result in a vector that is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, I've updated to reflect your points. @James you are totally right, I was incorrectly assuming that he'd be inserting at a point that already had data, which is not reflected in the question.

Comment: @markh44 What do you mean by "too large".  He wants to insert at position `x`, which means that the vector must have at least `x` elements in it _before_ we insert; otherwise, all he can get is undefined behavior.

Comment: @James Kanze I mean with the OPs code (with corrected use of sizeof), his vector would end up with size 2000+x, rather than 1000+x which he may have been expecting.  I see your answer correctly avoids this problem, for which your earned a +1 from me.

Comment: @markh44 Yes.  I see his resize also makes room for the array, although the insert will create any additional space needed.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to copy array to vector:

```
vec.resize(1000+some_position);//if needed
std::copy(A,A+1000,vec.begin()+some_position);
```

Comment: Why is it better? Is there a reason?

Comment: @Hindol, because copy and insert are different things. For example, if you insert `b[]={5,6} /*pseudocode*/` to position 2 of `a[]={1,1,1,1}`, you will get `{1,1,5,6,1,1}`, but if you coby `b`there, you will get `{1,1,5,6}`. The topicstarter wants to copy, but not insert. If he will use insert(), he may get terrible bugs later.

Comment: This is valid, and probably does what the OP wanted, but it isn't really idiomatic.  And given the way the question was worded, I'm not sure it really answers the question.  You're right to point out the difference between copy and insertion, but what does the OP really want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you believe sizeof() gives number of elements

e.g.

```
vec.resize(sizeof(A)+x);
```

but it doesn't. it gives the number of bytes.

the correct resizing should be something along the lines of

```
vec.resize(sizeof(A)/sizeof(int)+x);
```

of that follows that

```
vec.insert(vec.begin()+x, A, A+sizeof(A)/sizeof(int));
```

although I agree with Sergey that copy() is the better (more elegant) way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sizeof(A)` with `sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0])` and it will work.

And as @Sergey pointed out, `vec.resize();` in unnecessary in this case as `insert()` also resizes the `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `sizeof` is wrong.  `sizeof` is a very primitive operator,
which returns the number of *bytes* in the shallow image of the object
or type.  This is totally useless except for very low level programming.
If you need to deal with C style arrays, there functions `std::begin()`
and `std::end()` in C++11; in earlier versions of C++, we just wrote
them ourselves.  (I usually also wrote a `size()` function, which 
basically returned the number of elements.)  And `std::vector` works in
number of elements, not number of bytes.  So your last two lines of code
should be:

```
vec.resize( x );
vec.insert( vec.end(), std::begin( A ), std::end( A ) );
```

At least, that's what I think you're trying to do, based on the
comments: create an `std::vector<int>` with `x` elements initialized to
0, followed by the contents of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

**don't** *copy an array into a vector*. Use C++ to avoid that altogether. Instead of

```
void fill_array(int*, size_t);
int A[1000];
fill_array(A,1000);
std::vector<int> vec;
my_copy(vec,A);
```

simply do

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.resize(1000);    // or whatever
fill_array(vec.data(),vec.size());  // std::vector::data() is C++11
```

In C++ (also pre C++11) you would actually do this more like this:

```
template<typename iterator> fill_data(iterator begin, iterator end);
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.resize(n);    // make space (otherwise fill_data cannot fill in anything)
fill_data(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

then your `fill_data` is generic enough to be re-used for any type of container.

Comment: Your second example has undefined behavior.  You've got to resize the vector first.  The idea of calling the function directly on the vector is a good one, however: if you ensure that the vector is large enough beforehand, `fill_array( &A[x] )` can be used to avoid the intermediate C style array.  (On the other hand, since the OP obviously knows about `std::vector`, I'd guess that the `fill_array` function is something existing, which he cannot change.)

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for pointing that out. fixed now. `&A[x]` should not be used. It relies on `std::vector<>::iterator` to be a simple pointer, but that's not true for general containers (I don't know whether the standard requires this for `std::vector` or not). C++11 has introduced the member `data()` to avoid such hacks.

Comment: `&A[x]` is the standard solution, and works regardless of the type of iterator.  Iterators aren't even involved on the client side: `A[x]` returns a reference.  (On the other hand, for `&A[x]` to work, `x` must be strictly less than `A.size()`.  `&A[0] + x` might be better.  And yes, `A.data() + x` would be even better, _if_ you are sure you have C++11.

Comment: @JamesKanze IMHO `&A[x]` should be avoided in C++11

Comment: Why?  In this particular context, I would favor using `A.data()`, _if_ I were sure that I could count on C++11.  But in general, if I want the address of a specific element, `&A[x]` seems the most appropriate means of getting it.